# Sorted pandas dataframe returns different values depending formatting

Tags: python, pandas

When I sort this dataframe in descending order on "Total Purchase Value" without formatting it, it returns the top five rows correctly:

```
totalVal = topItems["Price"].sum()
topFiveItems = pd.DataFrame({
    "Item Name": itemNames,
    "Purchase Count": purchaseCount,
    "Item Price": itemPrices.map("${:.2f}".format),
    "Total Purchase Value": totalVal
})
topFiveItems.sort_values(ascending = False, by = "Total Purchase Value").head()
```

[Code without formatting & result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCdeC.jpg)

But when I apply formatting to "Total Purchase Value", for some reason the sorting changes:

```
totalVal = topItems["Price"].sum()
topFiveItems = pd.DataFrame({
    "Item Name": itemNames,
    "Purchase Count": purchaseCount,
    "Item Price": itemPrices.map("${:.2f}".format),
    "Total Purchase Value": totalVal.map("${:.2f}".format)
})
topFiveItems.sort_values(ascending = False, by = "Total Purchase Value").head()
```

[Code with formatting & result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohsn5.jpg)

Can anyone walk me through debugging this?

Thanks in advance for all your assistance

Comment: Hi Christina, it is always best practice to type your code with proper indentation into your question. It is very difficult for us to copy your code into a text editor and debug if it is in a picture (this means we have to type it out, and we are lazy). Please reformat your question with code as plain  text with proper indents.

Comment: Is that better? Is there a different way I should display the result?

Comment: Just to point out as well, your top 5 can be gotten by `top5 = df.groupby('SN')['Price'].agg(['count', 'sum', 'mean']).nlargest(5, 'sum')`... then as part of your final output for presentation you can rename and apply the formatting... (rule of thumb is leave datetimes as datetimes, numbers as numbers etc, until the last minute when you need to style them/present them in a specific way - that way you won't encounter issues with ordering/other bits)

Comment: Much easier for all those involved! Thanks (took away my downvote)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the format to include the '$' you are changing the data type to a string, so you're no longer sorting in descending numeric order, you're sorting in descending alphabetic order, so '9' comes before '1'.

Comment: Is there another method I can use for sorting the values? I tried .nlargest and it also returns an error that I cannot use this method on this object type.

Comment: @Christina I think just sorting first and then formatting will be what you want to do.

Comment: @Christina apply formatting *after* you've done calculations with numerics as numerics...

Answer (score 0):

[chet-the-wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6321559/chet-the-wizard) is probably right, verify your data types before and after

```
topFive.dtypes
```

will tell you what the data types are